# Telegram bot java: inline url button does not create an update and thus no callback data to respond on

Tags: java, telegram-bot

So i have this button which i want to be removed after it is clicked.
but clicking it does not generate an update?

```
if (Objects.equals(text.toUpperCase(), "TEST")){
            String out = link;
            try {
                SendMessage sendMessage=new SendMessage().setChatId(update.getMessage().getChatId()).setText("JOIN THE CHANNEL!");
                InlineKeyboardMarkup markupInline = new InlineKeyboardMarkup();
                List<List<InlineKeyboardButton>> rowsInline = new ArrayList<>();
                List<InlineKeyboardButton> rowInline = new ArrayList<>();
                rowInline.add(new InlineKeyboardButton().setText("JOIN").setCallbackData("JOIN_PREMIUM").setUrl(link));
                rowsInline.add(rowInline);
                markupInline.setKeyboard(rowsInline);
                sendMessage.setReplyMarkup(markupInline);
                sendMessage(sendMessage);
            } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

and to decide an action when it is pressed i have:

```
else if (update.hasInlineQuery()||update.hasCallbackQuery()||update.hasChosenInlineQuery()||update.hasPreCheckoutQuery()||update.hasShippingQuery()){
        String call_data = update.getCallbackQuery().getData();
        System.out.println("CALL DATA: "+call_data);
        int message_id = update.getCallbackQuery().getMessage().getMessageId();
        long chat_id = update.getCallbackQuery().getMessage().getChatId();

        if (Objects.equals(call_data, "JOIN_PREMIUM")){
            EditMessageText editMessageText = new EditMessageText().setMessageId(message_id).setChatId(chat_id);
            editMessageText.setText("Welcome to the club!");
            try {
                editMessageText(editMessageText);
            } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

but that is useless since it doesn't give an update, but is should!
Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: Any error message?

Comment: not at all, it does not generate an update. so nothing is received in the void onUpdateReceived(Update update)

Answer (score 1):

*url* and *callback_data* in *InlineKeyboardButton* are **optional** fields.

> You must use **exactly one of the optional fields**.

[documentation for InlineKeyboardButton](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inlinekeyboardbutton)

So, the problem is here:

```
rowInline.add(new InlineKeyboardButton()
            .setText("JOIN")
            .setCallbackData("JOIN_PREMIUM")
            .setUrl(link));
```

You should remove either

```
.setCallbackData("JOIN_PREMIUM")
```

or

```
.setUrl(link)
```

Also I have one not crucial remark. This line has a lot of redundancy

```
else if (update.hasInlineQuery()||update.hasCallbackQuery()||update.hasChosenInlineQuery()||update.hasPreCheckoutQuery()||update.hasShippingQuery())
```

You can shorten it to

```
else if (update.hasCallbackQuery())
```

Comment: How can I know if the user clicked the button with url ?